# How to set different color every gene and add legend in ChromoMap using R studio?

Tags: colors, legend

I have plot my data to make gene position in chromosome using [chromoMap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chromoMap/chromoMap.pdf).
here

[chr file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkzWD.png)

[chr anot file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLP5T.png)

and these are my scripts

> 

```html
library(chromoMap)
col.set = c("purple", "#4CBB17","#0096FF", "blue", "brown")
chr.data <- read.csv("chr_file.csv", header=T)
anno.data <- read.csv("chr_anot.csv", header = T)
chromoMap(list(chr.data),list(anno.data), labels = T, data_based_color_map = T,
          data_color = list(c(col.set)))
```

I got the result like this
[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl5ne.png)

I would like to set every gene with different color and add the legend.

Any idea what should I do? Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to color each gene with a unique color you just need to add a 5th data column to your annotations data `anno.data` lets say the names of your genes like:

```
anno.data <- cbind.data.frame(anno.data,Symbol=anno.data$element)
```

and then each of your gene will have the unique color. Also, for the legend you just need to set the `legend` argument to true.

here is the code with some additional configuration options for your plot:

```
chromoMap(list(chr.data),list(anno.data), 
          # labelling arguments 
          labels = T, 
          label_font = 12,
          label_angle = -55,
          # group annotation arguments
          data_based_color_map = T,
          data_type = "categorical",
          data_colors = list(c(col.set)),
          # for the  legend
          legend = T,
          #adjusting the legend along y-axis
          lg_y = 250,
          #increasing canvas width for legend
          canvas_width = 600,
          #playing with plot properties
          text_font_size = 12,
          chr_color = c("#d3d3d3"))
```

Thanks & Regards,

Lakshay(chromoMap developer)